# React - TypeError: this.props.courses.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http-headers, react-redux

I have created a react-redux application. Currently what it does is load courses from the server(api), and displays them to the course component. This works perfectly. I'm trying to add a feature where you can create a course by posting it to the server, the server would then true an a success object. However, when i post to the server i get the following error(see below). I think this is due to my connect statement listening for the load courses action. Clearly its thinking it should be getting a list of something, instead of a success object. I have tried a few thing for it to listen for both courses and the success response, but to save you the time of reading all the strange thing i have done, i could not get it to work. Dose anyone know how to fix this issue ?

error

```
TypeError: this.props.courses.map is not a function
```

course.component.js

```
    onSave(){
        // this.props.createCourse(this.state.course); 
        this.props.actions.createCourse(this.state.course); 
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="row">
                    <h2>Couses</h2>
                    {this.props.courses.map(this.courseRow)}
                    <input 
                        type="text"
                        onChange={this.onTitleChange}
                        value={this.state.course.title} />
                    <input 
                        type="submit"
                        onClick={this.onSave}
                        value="Save" />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
// Error occurs here 
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    courses: state.courses
  };
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(courseActions, dispatch)
    };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Course);
```

course.actions.js

```
export function loadCourse(response) {
    return {
        type: REQUEST_POSTS,
        response
    };
}
export function fetchCourses() {
    return dispatch => {
        return fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/test')
            .then(data => data.json())
            .then(data => {
                dispatch(loadCourse(data));
            }).catch(error => {
                throw (error);
            });
    };
}
export function createCourse(response) {
    return dispatch => {
        return fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/json', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                response: response
            })
        })
        .then(data => data.json())
        .then(data => {
            dispatch(loadCourse(data));
        }).catch(error => {
            throw (error);
        });
    };
}
```

course.reducer.js

```
export default function courseReducer(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'REQUEST_POSTS':
            return action.response;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

server.js

```
router.get('/test', function(req, res, next) {
  res.json(courses);
});

router.post('/json', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.json({response: 200});
});
```

i have tried added a response to the state, and listening for it in the map state to props, but still for some reason react is trying to map response to courses. Do i need a second connect method?

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    courses: state.courses, 
    resposne: state.resposne
  };
}
```

As you can see from the pictures response is getting mapped as courses and not as response.

Picture 
[image]

Comment: What does the project success response from the server look like? Can you post an example success response?

Comment: @VishwasSinghChouhan i have added the server code as well. Sorry i would add screen shots, but stack for some reason wont display them. The error is 99% occurring the in connect function. I followed the trace all the way down there. If i send back a course object, like i do for the load function, it works correctly. However, the props.courses gets updated. I just want to get the response object back and not set it to props.coures.

Comment: Can you cut all this down to purely the code that affects what you're asking about? I don't see anywhere why you've include `onTitleChange` for example.

Comment: @TankorSmash, is this better or still to much?

Comment: It's better but you've made the code unusable. If you are down to go even further, have the code here be basically runnable but still reproducing the issue. You could also trim out all the lines of code that aren't involved too.

Comment: @TankorSmash im down to go even further. What do you mean by basically runnable? ill chop some more out.

Comment: Check your callback function "this.courseRow" that you have passed into courses.map. Or display it in your question

Comment: In the callback for createCourse action, you do this: `dispatch(loadCourse(data));`. What is `data` at this point? If it's not an array then when your Course container re-renders the Course component, `courses.map` will fail as it's expecting an array of courses that it can map over.

Comment: @Michael Yeah we discovered why it fails, now we are trying to figure out how to map the response to props response. response is somehow getting mapped to courses. I want courses and response in my state, but for some reason only courses is there.

Comment: Well Alserda's repsonse below is probably what you need then. After you create a course, you're firing an action that says "here are all the courses". You need to create another action for a create course response and your reducer(s) needs changing to support that. Also Riaz's reply is worth a look - you might want to add another action and corresponding reducer function to add the new course to the end of the existing list after you get a successfull callback from the creation.

Comment: @Michael i just want to get the response object separate from the courses object, for right now. If that is possible.

Comment: I've added a possible solution - see if that helps.

Comment: Updated proposal below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Assumptions:**

1. `state.courses` is initially an empty array - from course.reducer.js
2. You don't call `fetchCourses()` action the first time you are rendering your view
3. Even if you call `fetchCourses()` there is no problem as long as `courses` in server.js is an array (the array in the response *replaces* the initial `state.courses`)

**Flow:**
Now I assume the first render is successful and React displays the `<input type="text">` and `submit` button. Now when you enter the title and click on the `submit` button, the `onSave()` method triggers the `createCourse()` action with parameter that is more or less similar to `{ title: 'something' }`.

Then you serialize the above mentioned param and send to the server (in course.actions.js -> `createCourse()`) which in turn returns a response that looks like `{response: 200}` (in server.js). Response field is an integer and **not an** array! Going further you call `loadCourses()` with the object `{response: 200}` which triggers the `courseReducer` in course.reducer.js

The `courseReducer()` **replaces** `state.courses` (which is [] acc. to assumption) with an integer. And this state update triggers a re-render and  you end up calling `map()` on an integer and not on an array, thus resulting in `TypeError: this.props.courses.map is not a function`.

**Possible Solution:**

1. Return a valid response from serve.js (i.e. return the `course` object the endpoint is called with), or
2. Update your reducer to add the new course object into the existing `state.courses` array, like, `return [...state, action.response]`

### Update:

Based on OP's comment, if what you want to do is send the new course object to the server, validate it and send success (or error) and based on response add the same course object to the previous list of courses, then you can simply call `loadData()` with the same `course` object  you called `createCourse()` with and (as mentioned above) inside your reducer, instead of replacing or mutating the old array create a new array and append the course object to it, in es6 you can do something like, `return [...state, course]`.

### Update 2:

I suggest you go through [Redux's Doc](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/). Quoting from [Redux Actions' Doc](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Actions.html)

> Actions are *payloads of information* that send data from your application to your store. They are the only source of information for the store.

The `createCourse()` action is called with a *payload* which is more-or-less like,
`{title: 'Thing you entered in Text Field'}`, then you call your server with an AJAX-request and pass the *payload* to the server, which then validates the payload and sends a success (or error) response based on your logic. The server response looks like, `{response: 200}`. This is end of the `createCourse()`action. Now you `dispatch()` `loadCourses()` action from within `createCorse()`, with the response you received from the server, which is not what you want (based on your comments). So, instead try `dispatch()`ing the action like this (try renaming `response` param, it's a bit confusing)

```
//.....
.then(data => {
  dispatch(loadCourse(response));  // the same payload you called createCourse with
})
//.....
```

Now, `loadCourse()` is a very basic action and it simply forwards the arguments, which Redux uses to call your `reducer`. Now, in case you followed the previous discussion and updates how you call `loadCourse()`, then the return from `loadCourse()` looks like

```
{
  type: REQUEST_POSTS,
  response: {
    title: 'Thing you entered in Text Field',
  }
}
```

which is then passed onto your `reducer`, specifically your `courseReducer()`.

Again quoting from [Redux Reducers' Doc](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html)

> *Actions* describe the fact that something happened, but **don't specify** how the application's **state changes** in response. This is the job of reducers.

The `reducer` must define the logic on how the action should impact the data inside the `store`.
In your `courseReducer()`, you simply returns the `response` field inside the `action` object and [expect] Redux to auto-magically mutate your state! Unfortunately this is not what happens :(
Whatever you return from the reducer, completely replaces whatever thing/object was there before, like, if your state looks like this

```
{ courses: [{...}, {...}, {...}] }
```

and you return something like this from your reducer

```
{ title: 'Thing you entered in Text Field'}
```

then redux will update the state to look like

```
{ courses: { title: 'Thing you entered in Text Field'} }
```

state.courses is no longer an Array!

**Solution:**
Change your reducer to something like this

```
export default function courseReducer(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'REQUEST_POSTS': 
      return [...state, action.response]
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

**Side Note**: This is may be confusing at times, so just for the sake of record, `state` inside `courseReducer()` is not the complete state but a `property` on the `state` that the `reducer` manages. You can read more about this [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html#splitting-reducers)

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me, i really appreciate it. Yeah, you understand it perfectly. However, i'm trying to get the response separate from the courses. I call the courses when the component is rendered. Now i want the user to be able to add a course. The server responses with a response object. I want to now display that response object somewhere else. While also displaying the already established courses. Make sense ?

Comment: In your router.post('/json'... method change what you are doing to { res.status(200); res.json(courses); }

Comment: Send me a PM, maybe i can better explain what I'm trying to do and/or why its going wrong.

Comment: added a screenshot to better explain my question.

Answer (score 1):

--Edit after reading a comment of you in a different answer, I've scraped my previous answer--

What you're currently doing with your actions and reducers, is that you're calling `loadCourse` when you fetched the initial courses. And when you created a new course, you call `loadCourse` too.

In your reducer you're directly returning the response of your API call. So when you fetch all the courses, you get a whole list of all your courses. But if you create a new one you currently receive an object saying `response: 200`. `Object`s don't have the map function, which explains your error.

I would suggest to use `res.status(200).json()` on your API and switching the response status in your front-end (or using `then` and `catch` if you can validate the response status, [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#request-config) has this functionality (`validateStatus`)).

Next I would create a separate action-type for creating posts and dispatch that whenever it's successful.

I would change your reducer to something like

```
let initialState = {
  courses: [],
  createdCourse: {},
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'REQUEST_POSTS':
      return {
        ...state,
        courses: action.response
      }

    case 'CREATE_COURSE_SUCCESS':
      return {
        ...state,
        createdCourse: action.response,
      }

    default: return state;
  }
}
```

I wouldn't mind looking into your project and giving you some feedback on how to improve some things (ES6'ing, best practices, general stuff)

Comment: I updated my question. Maybe this helps show you what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to get the response object, but it get mapped as courses. I want to map it as response.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the questions & answers so far, it looks like you need to do something like this:

1) Add a new action and dispatch this from your createCourse function

```
export function courseAdded(course, response) {
    return {
        type: 'COURSE_ADDED',
        course
        response
    };
}

export function createCourse(course) {
    return dispatch => {
        return fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/json', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                course
            })
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => {
                dispatch(courseAdded(course, response));
            }).catch(error => {
                throw (error);
            });
    };
}
```

2) Change your reducers to handle both fetching courses and adding a new course (we're using [combineReducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/UsingCombineReducers.html) to handle this here)

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

function response(state = null, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'COURSE_ADDED':
            return action.response;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

function courses(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'COURSE_ADDED':
            return [...state, action.course];
        case 'REQUEST_POSTS':
            return action.response;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default combineReducers({
    courses,
    response
});
```

3) Hook up to the new `response` state in your `connect` component

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        courses: state.courses,
        response: state.response
    };
}
```

4) Do something with this new `response` prop in your component if you want to show it e.g.

```
// this is assuming response is a string
<span className="create-course-response">
    Create Course Response - {this.props.response}
</span>
```

**UPDATE**

I've added support for adding the new course to the end of the existing course list, as well as handling the response. How you shape the state is completely up to you and it can be re-jigged accordingly.

In order for this code to work, you will need to add support for the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator). If you are using babel it can be done like [this](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/). Creating a new object is important to ensure that you don't mutate the existing state. It will also mean react-redux knows the state has changed. Spread operator isn't essential and this can be done with `Object.assign`, but that syntax is ugly IMO.

Comment: So i cant have two objects in an action? I have to have an action for courses prop and an action for my response prop.

Comment: An action is simply a JavaScript object, so you can put as little or as much in it as you like, provides it has a type key. I would suggest that fetching courses and creating a course are separate actions and should be treated as such. You could change the shape of the state in the reducer(s), but I would keep the actions separate personally.

Comment: How do i pass two objects to my component props. I want to pass a courses and a response in a single action. Even if i pass the courses and response together, they both get mapped to courses

Comment: @Michael This won't update the existing `state.courses` which means if the OP is displaying a list of courses in `state.courses`, the list won't update!